# Error while trying to run Jupyter Notebook on virtualenv

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, turi-create

I wanted to install and use Turi Create on my Windows 10 system and I followed this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@malondireads/installing-turicreate-on-windows-10-534e147a4792

However, I get an error when I try to run the 'jupyter notebook'. The error is as follows:

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5KW0.png)

Please help me fix this guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find an error in your description. Assuming that you have problem with opening jupyter-notebook.

As the output says you have to follow the link in the terminal to open jupyter-notebook.Because jupyter-notebook needs a web application to work.

You can copy the link in the 4th or 5th line in the command prompt and paste it in a browser to access jupyter-notebook.